# Prove that the subgroup $H$ is normal in the group $G$

Tags: group-theory

where $3|H| = |G|$ is odd

Attempt: Set $a$ in $H$ and $b$ in $G$ such that $bab^{-1}$ is not in $H$. Let $f\colon H\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ such that $f(a) = 0$ for $abH = bH$, $f(a) = 1$ for $abH = b^2$H. I need to prove that  $f$ is a homomorphism and $f(H) = {0}$. How do I do this?

Comment: Note that $|G:H| = |G|/|H| = 3$, and since $|G|$ is odd, $3$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$. There is a general theorem that if $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$, and $|G:H| = p$, then $H$ is normal. Try proving that.

Answer (score 1):

Just slightly modify your arguments: $H$ is a subgroup of index $3$, it has three cosets, say $H, xH, yH$. Define $F\colon G\rightarrow S_3$ by 
$$F(g)= 
\begin{pmatrix}
H & xH & yH\\
gH & g(xH) & g(yH)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Check that it is a homomorphism.

Where the elements of $H$ will go? For $h\in H$, 
$$F(h)= 
\begin{pmatrix}
H & xH & yH\\
hH & h(xH) & h(yH)
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
H & xH & yH\\
H & h(xH) & h(yH)
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
xH & yH\\
h(xH) & h(yH)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
So the image $F(h)$ is either identity or a $2$-cycle.

If $F(h)$ is $2$-cycle, then $2$ divides $|F(h)|$ and $|F(h)|$ divides $|h|$, which divides $|G|=odd$, contr.

So $H$ is in $\ker(F)$. Can $\ker(F)$ be whole $G$? For this, take $b\in G\setminus H$. What is $F(b)$? 
$$F(b)= 
\begin{pmatrix}
H & xH & yH\\
bH & b(xH) & b(yH)
\end{pmatrix}\neq Identity (why?).
$$
So $H=\ker(F)$ hence normal.

Comment: $|s|$ denotes order of element $s$ in group.